# catalog search full text Index error

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch, reindex

We just came across this issue where the catalog_search indexer was stuck and I just do what I always do reset the indexer and re-index it.

however, This time we received this error:[image]

We double checked the product, could not see any issues, so we deleted it in case we have done something wrong when we crated the product, even it is a long time we did.
Then we received this error when i tried to reindex again:
The Product with the "754.961.1016 THU754002" SKU doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what the issue was, it was related to a module I updated.